# horde or hordes

Tags: grammatical-number

When should I say "a horde" and when should I say "hordes"?

Would "hordes of brain-hungry zombies" be more zombies than "a horde of brain hungry zombies"? Or is one of these options incorrect?

Is it perhaps a bit like saying "a load of brains" versus saying "loads of brains"?

Comment: The plural in this case is just an intensifier for the singular. There would likely be no difference in the number of zombies you experienced.

Comment: If they're coming down the road it's a "hoard".  If they're coming from all directions it's "hoards".

Comment: _When should you say it?_ Best not to say anything, just quietly sneak away from your soon-to-be ex-companions and that should buy you some time to ponder whether the screams of _Eeeeek! A horde of zombies is munching it's way through my cranium_ or _Aaargh! Hordes of zombies are eating me from the feet up_ are grammatical or not. However I suspect that in the event of a zombie apocalypse _grammar_ will be the first thing to go and you probably needn't chastise someone too severely for shouting _Uuurgh! A hordes of zombie are ferociously nibbling on my extremities_.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

"hordes of" vs "a horde of" is an amplifier here, as already suggested in the comments.

If you want to be literal about it, one horde corresponds to [one group](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/horde), so "a horde of zombies" would refer to one tight group of zombies, while "hordes of zombies" would imply that there are several such groups.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a particular reference but personally I would use "a horde of..." if there was one specific large group. "hordes of" just means "an extremely large number of".

So, if there was a barbarian army of 2000 laying siege to a city, you could say "the horde of barbarians laid siege to the city". Whereas if you just wanted to make a generic statement about how many barbarians live on the plains, you could say "there are hordes of barbarians living on the plains".